# Remove/turn off default shader image in refracting object?

Tags: modeling, texturing, shaders, eevee-render-engine

2.92 version.  New file.  Object in viewport.

Material Properties!Surface!Roughness = 0

Material Properties!Surface!Transmission = 1

Material Properties!Settings!Screen Space Refraction: ticked

Render Properties!Screen Space Reflections: ticked

Render Properties!Screen Space Reflections!Refraction: ticked

Object appears in Eevee *Material Preview* with viewport's dark void background with a Blender-default garden picture file that fills the object, and in 6 DOF the garden imagery fills all of it.

Now I drop a sky dome over it, and then orbit:

[image]

Where the sky dome appears behind the refracting object, the Blender-default garden file imagery disappears,...but then reappears, resolving into some kind of cube of its own in the refraction.  (The coral colored box is a separate entity.)

The garden file imagery is here, in a shader/texture provided as a default by Blender:

[image]

How can that garden image be turned off inside the refracting object (at the very least when the sky dome appears in the background behind the refracting object)?